# Spawning a JOptionPane in a full screen application shows the taskbar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, joptionpane

I have a full screen (100%, even covers taskbars) application which sometimes asks for a password using a JOptionPane with a PasswordBox. My problem is that when the popup appears, you can see the system's taskbar at the bottom. It kind of looks like this:

```
    ----     popup
------------ taskbar
------------ fullscreen app
```

whereas I want the stack to stay like this:

```
    ----     popup
------------ fullscreen app
------------ taskbar
```

As long as my application is running I would like to fully hide the taskbar. This is the password box class I'm using:

```
public class PasswordBox {
    public String prompt() {
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
        int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pass,"Enter Password",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); 
        return new String(pass.getPassword());
    }
}
```

and I invoke it like this:

```
String tmpPASS = new PasswordBox().prompt();
```

If anyone needs more code I can easily provide it. I'm not sure how to tackle this problem and where to start. I gave up on the idea of "focus" because when the popup shows up it has focus.

Comment: Just for clarity, is this the Windows taskbar?

Comment: It's actually fine in Windows, Linux is giving me some issues. Currently testing on RHEL with Gnome

Comment: Consider the security implications of using  [`getPassword()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) as shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should pass the parent `JFrame` as the first parameter to the `JOptionPane`:

```
public class PasswordBox {
    public String prompt(JFrame fatherFrame) {
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
        int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fatherFrame, pass,"Enter Password",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); 
        return new String(pass.getPassword());
    }
}
```